# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm trying to create jstree but I want it to load after a few seconds,
I have a code that works but if I put it in another function for example setTimeOut I get an error Uncaught TypeError: $ (...). Jstree is not a function

This is my scripts:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
```

And if I put this code then everything is fine:

```
       <script>
        let cld;
        let rr = [{ text: "1001", id: "190", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "1002", id: "192", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "1004", id: "203", type: "3", children: true }
            , { text: "8002", id: "308", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "1007", id: "314", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "9001", id: "316", type: "3", children: true }
            , { text: "6513", id: "331", type: "3", children: true }];

        $('#tree').jstree({
                  'core': {
                      'data': function (node, cb) {
                             if (node.id === "#") {
                                  cb(rr);
                             }
                             else {
                                  cld = [{ text: "9001", id: "316", type: "3", children: true }
                                         , { text: "6513", id: "331", type: "3", children: true }];
                                   cb(cld);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
</script>
```

But if I put this code into a function setTimeOut for example:

```
 <script>
        let rr = [{ text: "1001", id: "190", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "1002", id: "192", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "1004", id: "203", type: "3", children: true }
            , { text: "8002", id: "308", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "1007", id: "314", type: "1", children: true }
            , { text: "9001", id: "316", type: "3", children: true }
            , { text: "6513", id: "331", type: "3", children: true }];

    setTimeout(function () {

        $('#tree').jstree({
                  'core': {
                      'data': function (node, cb) {
                             if (node.id === "#") {
                                  cb(rr);
                             }
                             else {
                                  cld = [{ text: "9001", id: "316", type: "3", children: true }
                                         , { text: "6513", id: "331", type: "3", children: true }];
                                   cb(cld);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }, 1000);

</script>
```

I get the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function
```

What's the problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: The `<script>` using `.jstree` is under the rest of your DOM, particularly under your `#tree` element and the three dependencies, right?

Comment: Yes it is inside the <head> tag in HTML

Comment: If the `<script>` tag with your code is inside `<head>`, then `#tree` won’t be available in the DOM. There is no reason to use `setTimeout` here. Either use the `defer` attribute, move your script to the bottom of the `<body>` or use `$(document).ready`. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). Even with the `setTimeout`, I cannot reproduce this issue. However, the code snippet where you say “everything is fine” does _not_ work.

Comment: Not the <head> tag has only the first three scripts and the script with the code is inside the body

Comment: .    someone??.......

Comment: The code you've provided does not have this problem. You should create a [mcve] which reproduces it.

Comment: What do you mean? This previous one does not work for me!